# Regular expression for extracting instance ID, AMI ID, Volume ID

Tags: java, regex

Given the following string

> Created by CreateImage(i-b9b4ffaa) for ami-dbcf88b1 from vol-e97db305

I want to be able to extract the following using a regular expression

> i-b9b4ffaa
>   ami-dbcf88b1
>   vol-e97db305

This is the regular expression I came up with, which currently doesn't do what I need :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Created by CreateImage([a-z]+[0.9]+)([a-z]+[0.9]+)([a-z]+[0.9]+)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("Created by CreateImage(i-b9b4ffaa) for ami-dbcf88b1 from vol-e97db305");
System.out.println(m.matches()); --> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match all words starting with letters, followed with a hyphen, and then having alphanumeric chars:

```
String s = "Created by CreateImage(i-b9b4ffaa) for ami-dbcf88b1 from vol-e97db305";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b[a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
// => i-b9b4ffaa, ami-dbcf88b1, vol-e97db305
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/qLaerT)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive modifier (embedded flag option)
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `[a-z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[a-z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumerics.

**To make sure these values appear on the same line after `Created by CreateImage`**, use a `\G`-based regex:

```
String s = "Created by CreateImage(i-b9b4ffaa) for ami-dbcf88b1 from vol-e97db305";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:Created by CreateImage|(?!\\A)\\G)(?:(?!\\b[a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+).)*\\b([a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/lnUNam).

Note that the above pattern is based on the `\G` operator that matches the end of the last successful match (so we only match after a match or after `Created...`) and a tempered greedy token `(?:(?!\\b[a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+).)*` (matching any symbol other than a newline that does not start a sequence: `word boundary`+`letters`+`-`+`letters|digits`) that is very resource consuming.

**You should consider using a two-step approach to first check if a string starts with `Created...` string, and then process it**:

```
String s = "Created by CreateImage(i-b9b4ffaa) for ami-dbcf88b1 from vol-e97db305";
if (s.startsWith("Created by CreateImage")) {
    Matcher n = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b[a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+").matcher(s);
    while(n.find()) {
        System.out.println(n.group(0)); 
    }
}
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/rT9Id4)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'd like it to include the prefix "Created by CreateImage" if possible

Comment: You can easily append it to the matched values, can't you? Or should the `Created by CreatImage` be checked for with a regex?

Comment: I'd like to be a part of the regular expression, yeah

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful, regular expressions are a real pain to me